# Script to remove unnecessary blank lines in C++ implementation files in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder structure like this:

```
----src/
        ----foo.cpp
        ----bar.cpp
```

`foo.cpp` is thus:

```
#pragma once

#include "foo.h"


void FOO::func1(){


    printf("Foo Func1\n");


}

void func2(){

    printf("Func2\n");
}
```

I want to rewrite this file where there is exactly one empty line between function implementations, and before and after one. That is, within any function implementation and outside of function implementations, I want all empty lines to be removed. I want `foo.cpp` to be transformed thus:

```
#pragma once
#include "foo.h"

void FOO::func1(){
    printf("Foo Func1\n");
}

void func2(){
    printf("Func2\n");
}
```

`bar.cpp` is likewise. Is it possible to write and run a script/batch (linux or windows is fine) that does this on all files in a given folder `/src/` in this case.

Other detail: My current way of doing this is to open up each file in `vim`, use `{` and `}` to navigate between `vim` paragraphs that takes me to the next empty line and `dd` delete that line if it is to be removed.

Comment: Only a C++ compiler fully understands C++ program source. If your existing C++ source fiels follow some common formatting conventions you could probably come up with a hand-tailored script to reformat the code based on its current formatting. Something like this will need to be tailored to the specific content in your source files, so you'll have to do the legwork yourself, noone on stackoverflow.com has full access to your files and perform the needed analysis on its current formatting.

Comment: My source codes are standard -- just like other C++ codes. I suppose a script has to keep track of open `{` and match it to closing `}` which could be challenging. It need not know anything more about the code. That is why I had tagged `c++` in the initial post. User @Ron for whatever reason edited the post to remove that tag.

Comment: @Ron Any script for this question should be aware, lexically, as to what constitutes a function. As far as I can tell, this is the first instance of `{` up until the matching `}` is found. There could be other languages with this structure but it is quintessential `C++`.

Comment: @oguz ismail Could you please clarify why you deleted the other tags? I would like to see if a solution is possible for this in bash, awk or vim.

Comment: I was going to vote to close as *needs more focus*, but since you've already got an answer I edited tags to limit the scope of question. Questions asking I want this in either A, B, or C language are too broad, and often a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"


FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.cpp" '
 ) DO >"%destdir%\%%a" (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=]" %%c IN ('find /n /v "" ^<"%sourcedir%\%%a"') DO (
  FOR /f %%t IN ("%%d") DO (
   ECHO %%d
   FOR %%m IN (} #include) DO IF /i "%%t"=="%%m" echo/
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The `%%a` loop assigns each `.cpp` filename in turn to `%%a`.

The `%%c` loop reads each line from the file and prefixes the line with a line number in square brackets using the `find` utility (note : Microsoft's `cmd` utility `find`) the resultant line is then tokenised, `[number` going to `%%c` and `remainder of line after ]` to `%%d`.

The `%%t` loop finds the first token on the line (if it exists) then regurgitates the line and adds a blank line if the first token was (any of the strings in the list processed by `%%m`) - I added `/i` to the `if` to make the match case-insensitive.

As a check, I'd use

```
fc /w "sourcedirectoryname\*.cpp" "destinationdirectoryname\*.cpp"
```

which should execute a file-compare between the original and processed files, disregarding whitespace.

The source directory and destination directory must be different, otherwise batch will attempt to overwrite the very file it's reading. No good will come of that.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to help me! I tried your batch file after specifying `sourcedir=src` and `destdir=dst` . `src` has two `.cpp` files, `dst` is initially empty. On running the batch file, the two files are copied into `dst`. However, they are unmodified. Moreover, `cmd` complains twice that the system cannot find the path specified. So, it appears some of the batch works, while some other parts dont. Could you help?

Comment: Very odd. If the system can't find the sourcefile, then how on Earth is it copying the sourcefile it can't find? Certainly works on my system. Ah, well - start the new year with a mystery... First step : As you're probably aware, batch is a little cranky at times. Best to copy/paste instead of retype. Also, check that you're using Microsoft's `find`. not something like the `cygwin` version. After that, we're down to debugging. I've used absolute paths - tried completely specifying the directories? Still no go? Try `>con echo %%a` on a new line before `for...%%c` which should show %%a

Comment: Ah, works perfectly! There was a typo in my path. Could I ask you where in your code is a `{` matched with the corresponding `}` to figure out the function scope? I can only find usage of a single `}` in your script.

Comment: It isn't. The code looks for either `}` or `#include` (the items in the `%%m` list) as the first token in any line. If either is the first token, then generate an extra newline. No doubt if you have nested braces, it'll inject that extra line for any `}` alone on a line. Also, it'll *not* generate a newline should nests be terminated by `}}`. Batch is a little simple-minded, but if you keep it simple, it'll do its best.

Comment: I see. Let me work on this to see if I can keep a count. Start with `count = 0`. Whenever a `{` is encountered, count is incremented. Whenever a `}` is encountered, count is decremented. If count becomes 0 then have a newline. Any other encountered newline should be removed. That way, nested `{`s and `}`s within a function should not trigger a newline. Thanks again for your help. I should be on my way with experimenting with this.

Answer (score 0):

vim solution:

```
  vim *.cpp
  :silent! argdo g/){$/,/^\}/ s/^\n//g 
  :silent! argdo g/\v(^\n){2,}/d | update
```

Explaining the above commands

```
  THE FIRST COMMAND
  opening all files with a wildcard we create in vim an arglist
  a list of all files we give as arguments

  THE SECOND COMMAND
  silently
  in all files of our argument list (the arglist)
  globally
  from /){/  
  until /^}/
  substitute
  ^\n  blank lines
  //   for nothing

  THE THIRD COMMAND
  \v  very magic (avoid many backslashes)
  (^\n) regex group matching blank lines
  {2,}  two or more
  d     delete
  update  -> write all files
```

You can populate your arglist with the find command:

```
 vim $(find *.cpp)
```

References:

- https://skayal.com/sed-delete-the-lines-lying-in-between-two-patterns/
- https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g